# Trying to change default link colours

Tags: css

```
.breadcrumb {
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
}
a.breadcrumb:link { color: white; }
```

I’m trying to change the default colors of my site’s breadcrumb links to white. I understand the `.link` `.hover` etc., & the importance of the correct order, but nothing I try changes the default site color styling. The only part of the breadcrumb trail that is white is the current page – all the others default to the site’s colors. I have also tried adding !important but no different.
I need to do this in CSS. Can anyone suggest why this isn't working for me?

Comment: I think you need this (you're not asking a clear question you want us to teach you):
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```css
.breadcrumb {
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
}

.breadcrumb a {
  color: red;
}

.breadcrumb a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.breadcrumb a:visited {
  color: yellow;
}

.breadcrumb a:active {
 color: cyan
 }
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumb">
  <a>This is some text<a/>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfection! Many Thanks .. Could you tell me how I would adapt that for .hover .active & .visited if possible please?

Comment: Absolutely spot on! I've struggled with that all morning. Cheers

Comment: @Leobs I suggest you learn basic CSS and HTML on YouTube. There is plenty of resources out there! Good luck!